Past perfect continuous vs Past perfect simple
Which one is correct or more common? (must choose one, can't say both)
I had lived in China for 20 years when I met him.
I had been living in China for 20 years when I met him.

They really are both "valid", so your "can't say both" isn't really helpful. But the first one would normally use before rather than when, which you've asked about separately.
